# Querying a XML FIle and creating a text file

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file :TableList.xml

```
<TableList>  
<Table>  
<TableName>TableA</TableName>  
<Columns>ColumnA1,ColumnA2,ColumnA3,ColumnA4</Columns>  
</Table>  
<Table>  
<TableName>TableB</TableName>  
<Columns>ColumnB1,ColumnB2,ColumnB3,ColumnB4</Columns>  
</Table>  
</TableList>
```

I want query this file using Linq-to-XML and for each of the values I want derive the following format

```
The table - TableA - has columns - ColumnA1,ColumnA2,ColumnA3,ColumnA4.

The table - TableB - has columns - ColumnB1,ColumnB2,ColumnB3,ColumnB4.
```

and have it created as a single text file - `TableDoc.txt` -at the end.

How can this be dome with brevity using Linq-to-XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can this be dome with brevity using Linq-to-XML?

I'll take this as a challenge for brevity...

```
File.WriteAllLines("TableDoc.txt", XDocument.Load("TableList.xml")
         .Descendants("Table")
         .Select(t => string.Format("The table - {0} - has columns {1}.",
                                    t.Element("TableName").Value,
                                    t.Element("Columns").Value)));
```

(Obviously remove all unnecessary whitespace for *real* brevity.)

That still leaves you the challenge of figuring out how/why it works, of course - and potentially refactoring it in a more readable way.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("TableDoc.txt"))
{
    XDocument doc=XDocument.Load("yourXML");//load document
    foreach(var elm in doc.Descendants("Table"))//takes all table elements
    {
    string s="The table-"+elm.Element("TableName").Value+"- has coloumns -"+elm.Element("Columns").Value;
      writer.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the (subjectively?) slightly more readable query expression version:

```
var columnsPerTable = from table in XElement.Load("TableList.xml").Elements("Table")
                      let name = table.Element("TableName")
                      let columns = table.Element("Columns")
                      select string.Format("The table - {0} - has columns - {1}.", 
                                           name.Value, columns.Value);
File.WriteAllLines("TableDoc.txt", columnsPerTable);
```

There's no need to use an `XDocument`, of course. `XElement` works just fine.